# How can I prove my adding a class worked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

This is an easy one I'm sure but I can't find anything searching or on Google.

If I use

```
document.getElementById(someId).className += " whateverClass";
```

or

```
$('#').addClass('whateverClass');
```

How can I prove this in the console? (So that I know that step is working correctly)

Comment: The easiest way would be to inspect the element in your DOM. Or possibly add a very distinct style to `.whateverClass`. Or with jQuery `$('#yourId.whateverClass').length > 0`

Answer (score 2):

Easy enough in jQuery by using [.hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/):

```
console.log( $('#someId').hasClass('whateverClass') );
```

You can execute this in your code or in the browser console itself.

Comment: I keep forgetting I can use things inside the console. Thank you!

Comment: Thankfully you can use multiple parameters if you have lots of things in the console going. `console.log("Here is my debug statement!", $('#someId').hasClass('whateverClass'));`

Answer (score 1):

You can check in the inspector (Right Click -> Inspect Element) and see if the element has the class added, or you can do `$("#selector")` in the console and check through the properties returned.

Failing that, do something in the CSS class that will visually confirm it has been added (bold text, red outline, capital letters, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a method for that.

```
if( $('#test').hasClass('whateverClass') ) {
   // Awesome code..
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, rightwa of add multiple class is

```
var el=document.getElementById(id);
el.classList.add("your-class");
```

**NOT**

```
document.getElementById(someId).className += " whateverClass";
```

In jquery, you can achieve this by simpily

```
$("#"+id).addClass("your-class");
```

You can check whether class is present or not

in jquery alert( $('#'+id).hasClass('your-class') )

Comment: Why is that the case? (I don't not believe you - I'm just wondering what the justification is)